# Como utilizar o subclipse no eclipse kepler do ubuntu 14.04 64 bits

Tags: java, eclipse, linux, ubuntu, svn

Já fiz todas as configurações indicadas no site: http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

E quando eu acesso o menu Team -> SVN apresenta a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = -/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/libsvnjavahl-1.so
```

Fiz o checkout do projeto por fora, via terminal:

```
svn checkout projeto
```

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa mesmo usar a JavaHL?
Caso não, você pode utilizar o SVNKit em `Window > Preferences > SVN > Opção SV Interface`  e escolher o Client SVNKit.

Se não existir a opção, é só instalar pelo Marketplace.